# Perform subtraction on table row based on the the input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering If the payment status is Y, can the price be subtracted accordingly. The amount yet to be paid will show the subtraction result

For example, in this case, since both 50 and 10 is paid,
the amount yet to be paid will be the "total (ie 70) minus (50+10)" = 10

Many thanks.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#myTable").on('input', '.txtCal', function () {
       calculate();
});

function calculate() {
var calculated_total_sum = 0;
     
       $("#myTable .txtCal").each(function () {
           var get_textbox_value = $(this).val();
           if ($.isNumeric(get_textbox_value)) {
              calculated_total_sum += parseFloat(get_textbox_value);
              }                  
            });
              $("#total_sum_value").html(calculated_total_sum);
}
       
calculate();
    

});
```

```html
<html>
<head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="myTable">
<tr>   <th width="100">Name </th>
    <th>Price</th><th>Payment status</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><span>A</span></td>
    <td><input type="text" class='txtCal' value="50" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class='status' value="Y" /></td>
</tr>    
<tr>
    <td><span>B :</span></td>
    <td><input type="text" class='txtCal' value="10" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class='status' value="Y" /></td>
</tr> 
   <tr>
    <td><span>C:</span></td>
    <td><input type="text" class='txtCal' value="10" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class='status' value="N" /></td>
</tr> 
<tr>
    <td><span><b>TOTAL  :</b></span></td>
    <td><b><span id="total_sum_value"></span></b></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><span><b>Yet to be paid</b></span></td>
    <td><b><span id="arrears"></span></b></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can check the payment status column for `N` and sum those values. Like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#myTable").on('input', '.txtCal, .status', function() {
    calculate();
  });

  function calculate() {
    var calculated_total_sum = 0;
    var to_be_paid = 0;

    $("#myTable tr").each(function() {
      var get_textbox_value = $('.txtCal', this).val();
      var get_payment_status = $('.status', this).val();
      
      if (get_textbox_value && get_payment_status) {
        if ($.isNumeric(get_textbox_value)) {
          calculated_total_sum += parseFloat(get_textbox_value);
        }

        if (get_payment_status === 'N') {
          to_be_paid += parseFloat(get_textbox_value);
        }
      }
    });
    $("#total_sum_value").html(calculated_total_sum);
    $("#arrears").html(to_be_paid);
  }

  calculate();


});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <th width="100">Name </th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Payment status</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>A</span></td>
      <td><input type="text" class='txtCal' value="50" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class='status' value="Y" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>B :</span></td>
      <td><input type="text" class='txtCal' value="10" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class='status' value="Y" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>C:</span></td>
      <td><input type="text" class='txtCal' value="10" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class='status' value="N" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span><b>TOTAL  :</b></span></td>
      <td><b><span id="total_sum_value"></span></b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span><b>Yet to be paid</b></span></td>
      <td><b><span id="arrears"></span></b></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: One more issues when the input filed is updated from N to Y, can the subtraction be trigger?

Comment: @tam - Updated to include the `.status` elements in the `.on()` to trigger the refresh.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be, getting the parent for every iteration, it might a little less performance friendly but here you go:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#myTable").on('input', '.txtCal', function () {
       calculate();
});

function calculate() {
var calculated_total_sum = 0;
var yet_to_be_paid = 0;
     
       $("#myTable .txtCal").each(function () {
           var get_textbox_value = $(this).val();
           
           if ($.isNumeric(get_textbox_value)) {
              calculated_total_sum += parseFloat(get_textbox_value);
              }  
              
           if($(this).parent().parent().find(".status").first().val() == "Y") {
            yet_to_be_paid += parseFloat($(this).val());
           }
      
              
            });
              $("#total_sum_value").html(calculated_total_sum);
              $("#arrears").html(calculated_total_sum - yet_to_be_paid);
              
}
       
calculate();
    

});
```

```html
<html>
<head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="myTable">
<tr>   <th width="100">Name </th>
    <th>Price</th><th>Payment status</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><span>A</span></td>
    <td><input type="text" class='txtCal' value="50" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class='status' value="Y" /></td>
</tr>    
<tr>
    <td><span>B :</span></td>
    <td><input type="text" class='txtCal' value="10" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class='status' value="Y" /></td>
</tr> 
   <tr>
    <td><span>C:</span></td>
    <td><input type="text" class='txtCal' value="10" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class='status' value="N" /></td>
</tr> 
<tr>
    <td><span><b>TOTAL  :</b></span></td>
    <td><b><span id="total_sum_value"></span></b></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><span><b>Yet to be paid</b></span></td>
    <td><b><span id="arrears"></span></b></td>
</tr>
</table>
```